# Asterisk ring out even when the client is offline

Tags: asterisk

I need to configure an Asterisk box to go to voicemail but only after X ringouts.

```
exten => 1234,1,Dial(SIP/ivan, 30)
exten => 1234,2,VoiceMail(777@mb_tutorial)
exten => 1234,3,PlayBack(vm-goodbye)
exten => 1234,4,HangUp()
```

The client in my case is a softphone client. If it does not running or not connected to the pbx then this would immediately redirect the caller to the voicemail. The 30 seconds wait time does not apply in this case when the phone (sip client) is unavailable.

How could I configure Asterisk to try to ring out at least 5 times (regardless the sip client is offline) then if there is still no answer drop the caller to the voicemail.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create a context in `extensions.conf` that just rings forever if you call it, and then dial both the extension you want to reach and that contex. This guarantees that it will always run the `Dial()` application for 30 seconds   before jumping to the voicemail. (Change the 30 seconds value as needed to get five ringtones... the period of ringtones can be found in the appropriate section of `indications.conf` for your country, so you can calculate how much time five rings are supposed to be.)

It can look something like this:

```
[noop]
exten => s,1,Wait(30)
same => n,Hangup

[your_context]
exten => 1234,1,Dial(SIP/ivan&Local/s@noop,30)
exten => 1234,2,VoiceMail(777@mb_tutorial)
exten => 1234,3,PlayBack(vm-goodbye)
exten => 1234,4,HangUp()
```

Calling the *noop* context will basically have no effect, and if `SIP/ivan` is available, then it will ring. If you are not hearing ringtones when calling the 1234 extensions, you can try different options:

1. First possibility, using call progress (avoiding answering the channel and thus having the caller possibly pay to hear ringtones... but does not always work, depending on the SIP provider):

   ```
   [your_context]
   exten => 1234,1,Progress
   exten => 1234,2,Ringing
   exten => 1234,3,Dial(SIP/ivan&Local/s@noop,30)
   exten => 1234,4,VoiceMail(777@mb_tutorial)
   exten => 1234,5,PlayBack(vm-goodbye)
   exten => 1234,6,HangUp()
   ```
2. Second possibility, generating ringtones as sound on the answered channel (meaning that the caller pays for the call while waiting for an answer too, because the call is actually answered):

   ```
   [your_context]
   exten => 1234,1,Answer
   exten => 1234,2,Playtones(ring)
   exten => 1234,3,Dial(SIP/ivan&Local/s@noop,30)
   exten => 1234,4,VoiceMail(777@mb_tutorial)
   exten => 1234,5,PlayBack(vm-goodbye)
   exten => 1234,6,HangUp()
   ```

   If you do not hear the ring tones while waiting, try adding a `,r` parameter to the `Dial` application:

   ```
   exten => 1234,3,Dial(SIP/ivan&Local/s@noop,30,r)
   ```

Comment: thanks for `,r`  - it may help me with roaming calls

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple choices based on how you're using Asterisk.

1. Using FreePBX or a similar interface:

Setup a ring group and set it to "ringall".  You can then specify how many seconds it will ring.

2. Using hand written dialplan code:

Setup a ringall queue in [queue.conf](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+queues.conf)

```
[ivan]
strategy = ringall
context = default
member => SIP/ivan
```

Adjust your dialplan similar to this:

```
exten => 1234,1,Answer
exten => 1234,n,Queue(ivan,t,,,30)
exten => 1234,n,VoiceMail(777@mb_tutorial)
exten => 1234,n,PlayBack(vm-goodbye)
exten => 1234,n,HangUp()
```

Comment: Example config lines would be super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The second answer cannot be considered as a solution, also the syntax changed long time ago.

It should be Queue(ivan,t,,,30) instead of Queue(ivan|t|||30).

In this case it does ring out to the SIP peers but those are "fake rings" the call is already established, therefore the caller have to pay the fee even for ringing. The first one I will try Today but I have a feeling that the problem with that will be that if Ivan is Offline and comes back online during the 30 sec period, he won't get the rings anymore. I hope I'm not right.

Thanks for the answers anyway.